# Cannot find module 'fs/promises' using JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I'm using nvm and I'm having this error when using jhipster. It was previously working when I'm not using nvm.

jhipster version: v7.9.3

node: v12.22.12

npm: 6.14.16

```
ERROR! Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
Require stack:
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/bootstrap/index.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/esm.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/environment-builder.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js
Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
Require stack:
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/bootstrap/index.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/esm.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/environment-builder.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js
- /Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/bootstrap/index.js:29:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/bootstrap/index.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/util/esm.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/environment-builder.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js',
    '/Users/xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster.js'
  ]
}
```

Anyone have any idea why is the error and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by using node 16.14.2

Comment: Yes this is the right way, by default JHipster is tested against latest LTS version of Node.